# How to test jQuery UI Spinner with selenium

Tags: jquery-ui, selenium

I have tried a couple of ways:

1. Set value as regular input, doesn't work for me because the value is bound to a variable and it overrides.
2. Trigger the arrow up event like:

   find('#my_spinner').send_keys :arrow_up
3. Tried to trigger the click event for 'ui-icon-triangle-1-n', no success.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simulate the click on spin buttons like this:

```
find('.ui-spinner-up').click
find('.ui-spinner-down').click
```